# Problem with using classes to get elements of a name

Tags: python, class

I have this code for a name.  When get_middle, get_last, get_suffix, and get_name are called, they all return none.  I think there is a problem with splitting the elements in name, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Thank you for your help!

```
class Name:

    def __init__(self, name = ''):
        self.name = [(elem) for elem in name.split()]
        self.count = len(self.name)

    def set_first(self, value):
        self.name.append(value)

    def set_middle(self, value):
        self.name.append(value)

    def set_last(self, value):
        self.name.append(value)

    def set_suffix(self, value):
        self.name.append(value)

    def get_first(self):
        if len(self.name) >= 1:
            return self.name[0]
        else:
            return False

    def get_middle(self):
        if len(self.name) >= 3:
            return self.name[1]
        else:
            return False

    def get_last(self):
        if len(self.name) == 2:
            return self.name[1]
        if len(self.name) > 2:
            return self.name[2]
        else:
            return False

    def get_suffix(self):
        if len(self.name) == 3:
            return self.name[2]
        if len(self.name) > 3:
            return self.name[3]
        else:
            return False

    def get_count(self):
        return self.count

    def get_name(self):
        for item in self.name:
            print(item, end = ' ')

    def get_initials(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Creating an instance like `n = Name("Steve S Smith")` and the calling `n.get_first()` returns "Steve". Maybe you can show how you're using this.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of input, expected output, and how you're initializing instances of the class? Upon testing with my name like so `Name("James R McHugh")`, I received the expected output for all the functions.

Comment: So I am using a homework submission service for this problem, and it looks like it is running specific tests where it runs, for example, get_last with only using 'Gates', instead of running a full name and testing it.  I fixed that problem now by changing the else statement to just return the name.  However, get_name is still not working even after edits.  If anyone knows how to fix that, I would greatly appreciate the help!